Image URI problems after using Ucrop
I want to choose an image from the Gallery and crop it with a one to one ratio and display it, when clicked it is supposed, to open the gallery again and repeat the whole process, when I do it for the first time, it executes without any problems, when I try to replace the image I can choose and crop an image but it will not be replaced and the first image will remain in place. If I skip the cropping process then the aspect ratio will be whatever but the image will be replaced successfully so I believe that there is a problem with the URI passing of the ucrop function, Thanks in advance, here are my functions:
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        data?.data?.let { uri ->

            imageUri = uri

            startUCrop(uri)  //i can leave it out


        photoView.loadUri(uri)
    }
} else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    val resultUri = UCrop.getOutput(data!!)
    resultUri?.let {

        photoView.loadUri(it)


        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val sharedPreferencesKey = "imageUri_$name"


        with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
            putString(sharedPreferencesKey, it.toString())
            apply()
        }
    }
} else if (resultCode == UCrop.RESULT_ERROR) {
    val cropError = UCrop.getError(data!!)
    cropError?.let {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Crop error: ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

}
and the startUcrop, which if called prevents the update of the Pictures:
private fun startUCrop(uri: Uri) {
    val destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(File(cacheDir, "cropped"))

    UCrop.of(uri, destinationUri)
        .withAspectRatio(1f, 1f)
        .start(this)
}

further functions, that should not be relevant but might be:
val defaultImageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://${packageName}/${R.drawable.programm}")
        val name = intent.getStringExtra("name")
        val sharedPreferenceKey = "imageUri_$name"

        // Get the saved image URI from SharedPreferences
        val savedImageUriString = sharedPreferences.getString(sharedPreferenceKey, null)

        // Check if there's a saved image URI, otherwise use the default one
        imageUri = savedImageUriString?.let { Uri.parse(it) } ?: defaultImageUri



photoView = PhotoView(this).apply {
            id = R.id.photo_view
            layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            setZoomable(true) // Enable zoom and pan
            loadUri(imageUri) // Custom method to load image using Glide
        }


private fun PhotoView.loadUri(uri: Uri) {
        val radius = 80
        val requestOptions = RequestOptions().transform(RoundedCorners(radius))
        Glide.with(this.context)
            .load(uri)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.programm) // Optional: Add a placeholder image
            .error(R.drawable.black) // Optional: Add an error image
            .into(this)
    }

thanks in advance again I'm working for the first time with URIs so excuse me if I am simply stupid, but I am getting a little crazy as I can't understand when and why things work.
